# Схема умножения на фиксированный многочлен на Verilog

Tags: электроника, verilog, system-verilog

Хочу реализовать быстрый умножитель на константный многочлен из книги. Вот схема

[image: схема]

По этой схеме я написал такой код на верилоге:

```
module multiplier(
    input logic clk,
    input logic reset,
    input logic in,
    output logic out
);

    reg [2:0] s;
    
    always @(posedge clk)
        if (reset)
            s <= '0;
        else begin
            s[2] <= in;
            s[1] <= s[2];
            s[0] <= s[1];
        end
        
    assign out = in ^ s[2] ^ s[0];
endmodule
```

И тестбенч к нему:

```
module multiplier_tb();

    logic clk;
    logic reset;
    logic in;
    logic out;
    
    initial begin
        clk = 0;
        forever #5 clk = ~clk;
    end
    
    multiplier m(clk, reset, in, out);
    
    initial begin
        #1 reset = 1; #10
        reset = 0;
/*        
        // data 11111
        in = 1; #10
        in = 1; #10
        in = 1; #10
        in = 1; #10
        in = 1; #10
        // tail
        in = 0; #10
        in = 0; #10
        in = 0; #10
        $stop;
*/

       // data 1000
       in = 0; #10
       in = 1; #10
       in = 0; #10
       in = 0; #10
       in = 0; #10
       // tail
       in = 0; #10
       in = 0; #10
       in = 0; #10
       $stop;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk)
        #2 $write(out);
endmodule
```

Но на последовательности f(x) = 1000 схема работает неправильно. По математический расчетам должно получиться 1101000 - результат умножения многочлена g(x) = x^3 + x^2 + 1 на x^3. В логе симулятора получается такое: x00010000$stop
Тут непонятно откуда появился икс, а последовательность бит вообще другая какая-то. Скажите, пожалуйста, как правильно реализовать эту схему и симулировать ее, чтобы получился верный результат.

Comment: ну а что нельзя в вашем симуляторе вытащить s[2:0]  после каждого такта? первый x видимо потому, что на первом такте ещё сброс не сработал

Comment: Я новичок в верилоге, почти ничего не знаю тут, но очень интересно. К сожалению, содержимое сдвигового регистра мне ничего не говорит.

Comment: да я тоже почти не знаю, на vhdl программирую, но как же не говорит если сд. рег. определяет результат